# Angular Date pipe to adopt all timezone including IST

Tags: javascript, angular, date, pipe

I am using angular 5 and date pipe to format the date. `resDate` is String data type and rformat is `Thu Jul 01 12:57:25 CDT 2021`.
this needs to be converted as below format

```
{{resDate |  | date:"MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"} -->  06/22/21 05:35 PM
```

this code works for CDT timezone and throws error for IST time as "InvalidPipeArgument: 'Mon Jun 21 19:01:32 IST 2021' for pipe 'DatePipe'"

```
Thu Jul 01 12:57:25 CDT 2021 // working
Mon Jun 21 19:01:32 IST 2021 // not working
```

how to utilize date pipe to adopt all timezone. if that is not possible, format only CDT time and leave date as it is for IST to prevent from errors. I searched for many answers but couldn't find the correct approach.

Comment: Note: there are 3 different *standard times* which use the IST abbreviation *just to remember that 3 and 4 letter times are seldom unique, and surprises arise often

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the `resDate` variable is a String, looking at the documentation here - https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe Date pipe requires the input to be type number which is the Unix time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'date-pipe',
 template: `<div>
   <p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>
   <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
   <p>The time is {{today | date:'h:mm a z'}}</p>
 </div>`
})
// Get the current date and time as a date-time value.
export class DatePipeComponent {
  today: number = Date.parse('04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 PST');
}
```

Hope this helps to resolve your query. You just need to format your string into a Date object.

Comment: I still need to convert the string to the required format

Comment: You could always use `Date.parse()` and pass this to the template. I have edited the answer to make it a bit more legible